# Mysql query for calculating stock of books in library

Tags: mysql

I have three tables tblinventory, tbldisbursement, tblmissinglost. I want to calculate the total stock of books after deducting disbursements and returns for the current day.

```
select bn.No_of_books_procured 
     - (count(mis.Unr_ret_donated_discareded))
     - (count(case when dis.dis_disbursed_return = 1 
                   then dis.dis_disbursed_return end ) )as Stock 
  from tbl_inventorylibbooks bn 
 right 
  join tbl_limgt_booksmissing_lost_adjust mis 
    on mis.Book_Name_missingbk = bn.Id_inventory
  left 
  join tbllibmange_disbursement dis 
    on dis.dis_book_name_fk_id = bn.Id_inventory
 where bn.Id_inventory = 14
```

On few entries I get the correct answer and the other results entries the query is showing wrong answers. Can you kindly provide a solution for this?

tblinventory

```
id  Name
----------   
1   xyz
```

consider total books procured=10

tbldisbursement

```
**booknameFK  disbursed/returned**
---------------------------------------- 
Booknafk1                 1
Booknafk2                 0 
Booknafk3                 1
```

where 1=disbursed  and 0=returned

tblmissinglost

```
**id BooknameFk  missng**
---------------------------------------- 
1    Booknafk1    lost
2    Booknafk1    lost 

----------------------------------------
```

**Also check this query**

```
select (bn.No_of_books_procured) as procured,
    count(distinct mis.Id_missingbooks_pid) as missing,
    count( case when bs.dis_disbursed_return!=0 then  
    bs.dis_disbursed_return end) as disbursed
from tbl_limgt_booksmissing_lost_adjust mis
join tbllibmange_disbursement bs on
mis.book_name_missingbk=bs.dis_book_name_fk_id           
join tbl_inventorylibbooks bn on bs.dis_book_name_fk_id=bn.Id_inventory
where bn.Id_inventory=14 group by bn.Id_inventory
```

I am getting duplicate entries

[image: this is the result of above query]

Comment: Can you include current and desired output?

Comment: Please, edit your post to include the table structures and sample data.

Comment: Also, I'm not seeing dates to filter by current day. This means those tables hold only current day records?

Comment: Duplicates happen typically when you have the same book appearing multiple times in one of your other tables. Is it possible you have multiple disburse for the same book in tbldisbursement?

Comment: ya but book id will be different

Comment: you can do left joins and use "id" IS NOT NULL / IS NULL for counters, also in tblmissinglost you have two times the same bookname missing, is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

Select Sum(BookCount) Stock from (
Select Name , 1 BookCount from tblinventory
Union
select booknameFK Name , Case when disbursedORreturned=1 then -1 else 1 end as BookCount from tbldisbursement
Union
select booknameFK Name , -1 BookCount from tblmissinglost
)T

This will give you total number of books in stock as of now.